# Time taken for a rocket to reach a height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science

My doubt is a rather silly, simple one but i cant seem to understand what's wrong.

Let's assume a rocket is moving up with a constant acceleration of $a$, is moving strictly vertically(no gravity turns, etc.) and reaches a height $h$. Obviously the time taken should be
$t=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{a-g}}$(net acceleration is $a - g$). But in this case $h$ has a bigger significant value, so that gravity also changes with height. I tried to do the following(which obviously is false):
$$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=(a-g(\frac{R}{R+ds})^2)$$
I've tried the binomial expansion aswell:
$$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=(a-g(1-2\frac{ds}{R}))$$
The problem here is i cant integrate the above integral. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: You've mentioned that the rocket is moving up with a constant acceleration a ,then how is the net acceleration (a-g) and not a? I think you need to edit your question.

Comment: @Arjun The rocket itself due to the fuel is producing thrust which produces an acceleration of a. Not the net being a

Comment: Alright it that case $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$ =$(a−g(\frac{R}{R+h})^2)$

Comment: Almost but i'm not dure abt the left side. Isn't it $\frac{ds}{(dt)^2}$

Comment: No you can't use s=(1/2)at^2 to differentials like that, the mentioned formula comes from integrating d^2s/dt^2 = acceleration twice (and applying initial conditions)

Comment: ohh right yea totally forgot abt the actual definition. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the notation of differentials a bit. Let's consider the notation more in detail.

\begin{align}
a&=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}s\right)
\end{align}
Now hit both sides with a $\int dt$:

\begin{align}
\int a\,dt&=\int\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}s\right)dt\\
&=\int d\left(\frac{d}{dt}s\right)
\end{align}
What is this weird looking right hand side? Well, consider that $\int df=f+c$. Now we have
\begin{align}
\int a\,dt&=\int d\left(\frac{d}{dt}s\right)\\
at+C_1&=\frac{d}{dt}s
\end{align}
Repeating the same trick, we get
\begin{align}
\tfrac 1 2at^2+C_1t+C_2&=s
\end{align}

Comment: Yea thanks for making it clear. I had actually forgot abt the definition of acceleration. Thanks again

Comment: I remember being confused about this myself, glad I could help

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but could you solve the integral. $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=a-g(\frac{R}{R+ds})^2$